# A Salute to Poetry

Tags: riddle, knowledge, cipher, steganography, anagram

In honor of National Poetry Day (which happens to be March 21st - go figure), I have crafted a puzzle which I hope will do a small bit of justice to this day.

Carefully hidden in the four sections below (which may or may not be related) are **the names of five of my favorite poets** (admittedly, I have more than five). Some of the verse quoted below comes from well-known poets - but note that **any author whose work appears in this puzzle is not one of the final five poets**.

---

## Section I

> `We  should  have  a land  of sun,`
>
> **Of  gorgeous  sun**,
>
> `And  a land  of fragrant  water`
>
> `But limped on, blood-shod. All went lame; all blind;`
>
> **Drunk with fatigue; deaf even to the hoots**  5
>
> `Of tired, outstripped Five-Nines that dropped behind.`
>
> `Wast present, and, with mighty wings outspread,`
>
> **Dove-like sat'st brooding on the vast Abyss,**
>
> `And mad'st it pregnant: what in me is dark`
>
> `Pouring as wide a flood`  10
>
> **As when my brothers long ago,**
>
> `Came with me to the wood.`
>
> `As traceless as a thaw of bygone snow;`
>
> **It seemed to mean so little, meant so much;**
>
> `If only now I could recall that touch.`   15

## Section II

`15.6.2--4.2.3--10.1.5--1.5.1--7.5.6--0.0.0--8.1.1--15.4.1--15.8.4--5.1.5--5.3.4--2.3.3--11.1.2--10.5.3--14.4.4`

## Section III

> Ole pal Grenada

## Section IV

My prefix is shiny and precious.

My infix is archaically long ago.

My suffix contains German beer.

I heard of something ending once,

So I wrote about it, of course!

## Hints

Hint 1:

> Some pretty big hints were here the whole time. I bet you never even saw them. Literally did not see them. Hmmm...

---

*Again, the final answer is the names of five prominent poets. A **complete** answer is required for the checkmark (although partials are fine, as long as they are significant).*

Comment: Should the third-from-last line be bolded rather than code-formatted?

Comment: @Deusovi nope, I don't think so.

Comment: @Randal'Thor you and Omega are both on the right track. I'll wait a bit to drop a hint about the fifth poet (and the bonus sixth poet?)

Comment: Updated my answer following the hint. You sneaky devil :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Section I

Lines 1-3:

> ["Our Land" by Langston Hughes](https://www.poetrynook.com/poem/our-land-1).

Lines 4-6:

> ["Dulce et Decorum Est" by Wilfred Owen](https://www.laphamsquarterly.org/states-war/dulce-et-decorum-est).

Lines 7-9:

> ["Paradise Lost" by John Milton](http://www.paradiselost.org/lmg/Book-1.html).

Lines 10-12:

> ["Dirge" by Ralph Waldo Emerson](https://emersoncentral.com/texts/poems/dirge/).

Lines 13-15:

> ["The First Day" by Christina Rossetti](https://gladdestthing.com/poems/the-first-day).

So one of your favourite poets is

> HOMER (the last names of these five form an acronym H, O, M, E, R).

### Section II

Taking each three-number code $m.n.p$ to mean

> the $p$th letter of the $n$th word of the $m$th line in the section above,

another of your favourite poets is

> EMILY DICKINSON.

### Section III

Another of your favourite poets is

> EDGAR ALLAN POE, an anagram (I noticed the [anagram](/questions/tagged/anagram) tag!) of the letters "Ole pal Grenada".

Thanks @Deusovi for help with this!

### Section IV

Thanks to @OmegaKrypton for all but the suffix here.

*My prefix is shiny and precious.*

> SILVER.

*My infix is archaically long ago.*

> ERST.

*My suffix contains German beer.*

> STEIN.

*I heard of something ending once,*
*So I wrote about it, of course!*

> Apparently Shel Siverstein is famous for a [poem](http://famouspoetsandpoems.com/poets/shel_silverstein/poems/14836) entitled "Where the [Pavement] Ends".

### Miscellaneous

Following Hint 1, we should

> check the hidden text in the HTML markdown of the question. In Section I we should apparently look for "certain digits of a certain day" (the National Poetry Day mentioned in the intro) - as found by Bananenkopp in [their answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/85062/5373) this gives ROBERT FROST. Finally, as an extra bonus, there's a bit near the end which makes E. E. CUMMINGS (clued by lower-case writing style) the bonus sixth poet.

### Summary

> Five of your favourite poets are Homer, Emily Dickinson, Edgar Allan Poe, Shel Siverstein, and Robert Frost, with the extra bonus sixth of E. E. Cummings.

Comment: Section III must be rot13(rqtnenyyracbr). And I believe the fifth one might be rot13(senapvffpbggxrl, orpnhfr vs yvar guvegrra unf gur vapbeerpg sbeznggvat, gnxvat pbqr = N naq obyq = O sbezf uvf fheanzr va gur Onpba pvcure.)

Comment: @Deusovi Section III - duh, that's one of my favourite poets too, I should've got it. Thanks! For the fifth one ... hmm, not totally convinced. That's not a well-known poet, and it relies on an error in the OP. I'll leave a comment on the question to confirm if there's an error ... oh wait, you already did :-)

Comment: @Deusovi just now saw your guess on the last poet. No bacon is needed to unlock the key ;). FWIW, rot13(gur pbqr-sbeznggrq yvarf va Frpgvba V rkvfg fbyryl sbe rnfr bs tbbtyvat naq rnfr bs rapvcurevat va gur arkg frpgvba. V zvtug unir whfg chg gur obyqrq yvarf, ohg l'nyy jbhyq unir unq n urpx bs gvzr svaqvat gur nhgube bs gur yvar "bs tbetrbhf fha.")

Comment: I'll go ahead and spill the beans. rot13(Gur fvkgu cbrg jnf bs pbhefr n serrovr gung jnfa'g ernyyl erdhverq, SLV. Naljnl. sbe gur svsgu cbrg: erzrzore, Cbrgel Qnl vf Znepu **21**. Fb lbh gnxr gur frpbaq yrggre bs _fbzrguvat_ gb trg gur svsgu cbrg, naq gur svefg yrggre bs gur nhgube'f anzrf gb trg "Ubzre.")

Comment: Also think slightly less precious and less colorful. :) Omega's got the correct solution for that poet.

Comment: @Brandon_J Huh, Omega's solution is correct? I'd just assumed it wasn't: that person doesn't seem to be primarily a *poet*, and there was no explanation for the 4th-5th lines.

Comment: [The poem](http://famouspoetsandpoems.com/poets/shel_silverstein/poems/14836). Book of poems named after it. TBH I had no idea he did anything other than poetry; I only knew of the books [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=shel+silverstein+poetry+books&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS801US801&oq=shel+silverstein+poetr&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.7635j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Very large part of my childhood, and he seemed fairly well-known. To be fair, Poe wasn't primarily a poet, either, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Brandon_J I hadn't heard of Silverstein before, so I was just going by Wikipedia's description, which says he's "*known for his cartoons, songs, and children's books*". Poe, by contrast, is "*best known for his poetry and short stories*".

Comment: @Rand al'Thor Maybe you can include my answer to Section I so we have it all together?

Answer (score 10):

### Section IV

> [SILVERSTEIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shel_Silverstein)

My prefix is shiny and precious.

> SILVER

My infix is archaically long ago.

> [ERST](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/erst#English)?

My suffix contains German beer.

> STEIN. (thanks @Randal'Thor!)

I heard of something ending once,

So I wrote about it, of course!

Comment: can anyone please explain the downvote? thanks!

Comment: @BrandonJ is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: Yep! Sorry - must not have seen the ping. My bad.

Answer (score 4):

**Section I**, the fifth Poet

> As mentioned by Brandon_J in the comments, March 21 means "take the second letter of something". Well, take it from the bold lines of section I:
>
>  
>  O**f** gorgeous sun,
>  D**r**unk with fatigue; deaf even to the hoots
>  D**o**ve-like sat'st brooding on the vast Abyss,
>  A**s** when my brothers long ago,
>  I**t** seemed to mean so little, meant so much;
>
>
>  And now its getting cold: Its Robert Lee **FROST**

Comment: Good find! Thanks for the ping in comments on my answer, otherwise I might not have noticed this.